# 3-D Geometry Problem. Find a curve which touches the straight line.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves, solid-geometry

If two perpendicular tangent planes to paraboloid  $x^{2}+y^{2}=2z$  internsects in a straight line in the plane $x=0$, obtain the curve to which the straight line touches.

I don't know how to proceed in this question as I am very poor in the 3-D Geomentry. Can Someone help me in this questions. I want a general approach to solve these type of questions.

Comment: Could you please clarify "curve to which the straight line touches?"

Comment: @Hrhm This was question given in the paper. And according to me, in this question we have to find such a curve on which that straight line is tangent to curve.

Comment: Any curve that is tangent to that line? (Sorry, I'm just a little confused)

Comment: there should be a specific curve to which this straight line is a tangent. but i don't know how to determine it.

Comment: The intersection of the two tangent planes is a family of straight lines lying on the $yz$-plane. You are essentially asked to find the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29) of the family of straight lines. Once you figure out a parametrization for that family, follow method outlined in wiki will give you the curve. If I didn't make any mistake, it is a parabola.

Comment: @achillehui The original problem says **perpendicular** tangent planes, so isn't there only 1 possible line?

Comment: @Hrhm there are infinitely many pairs of them. For every point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve $x^2 = y^2+1$, the pair of tangent planes at $(\pm x_0, y_0, \frac{x_0^2 + y_0^2}{2})$ are perpendicular to each other and their intersection lies on the $yz$-plane.

Comment: @achillehui, You are so right, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Let the tangent planes touch the surface at $(x', y',z')$ and $(x'',y'',z'')$ be

$$\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    x'x+y'y &=& z+z' \\
    x''x+y''y &=& z+z''
  \end{array}
\right.$$

respectively.

The line of intersection $(\xi, \eta, \zeta)$ is
$$(\xi, \eta, \zeta)=
\left(
  \frac{\begin{vmatrix} \zeta+z' & y' \\ \zeta+z'' & y'' \end{vmatrix}}
       {\begin{vmatrix} x' & y' \\ x'' & y'' \end{vmatrix}},
  \frac{\begin{vmatrix} x' & \zeta+z'  \\ x'' & \zeta+z'' \end{vmatrix}}
       {\begin{vmatrix} x' & y' \\ x'' & y'' \end{vmatrix}},
  \zeta
\right)$$

For $\xi=0$, $$ \left \{ \begin{align*} y'&=y''\\ z'&=z'' \end{align*} \right.$$

Note the normals for the tangent planes are $(x',y',-1)$ and $(x'',y'',-1)$.

For perpendicular tangent planes,

\begin{align*}
  x'x''+y'y''+1 &= 0 \\
  x'x'' &= -(1+y'^2)
\end{align*}

Also, $x'x''$ is the product of roots of $x^2+y'^2 = 2z'$,

$$x'x'' = -(1+y'^2) = y'^2-2z'$$

Let $t=y'$, then $(x',y',z')$ and $(x'',y'',z'')$ are given by
$$\begin{pmatrix} \pm \sqrt{1+t^2} \\ t \\ t^2+\frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$

Now

$$(\xi, \eta, \zeta)=
\left(
  0, \frac{t^2+\frac{1}{2}+\zeta}{t}, \zeta
\right)$$

and the family of the intersection,
$$F(Y,Z;t)=tY-Z-t^2-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=0 \implies t=\frac{Y}{2}$$

The envelope is $$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    Y^2 &= 4Z+2 \\
    X &= 0
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

Comment: thanks for this good solution. I didn't understand the last part so can you please explain last part starting from "$\mathbf \ and \ the \ family \ of \ the \  intersection$ ". These two equations i didn't understand.

Comment: It's a way to find the envelope.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)

Comment: Thank you very much. This article is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two points at which the tangent planes touch the paraboloid:

$\left(x_1, y_1,\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{2}\right)$ and $\left(x_2, y_2,\frac{x_2^2+y_2^2}{2}\right)$

The tangent planes to these points are:

$z-\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{2}=x_1(x-x_1)+y_1(y-y_1)$ and $z-\frac{x_2^2+y_2^2}{2}=x_2(x-x_2)+y_2(y-y_2)$.

(This is from the equation $z-z_0=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$)

The intersection of these two lines must be parallel to the vector $( x_1,y_1,1)\times( x_2,y_2,1)$ whose $x$-component equal to $y_1-y_1$. Since the $x$-component must be equal to $0$, we conclude that $y_1-y_2=0$. In other words, $y_1=y_2$. In order to avoid confusion, let us define a new variable $y_3=y_1=y_2$.

Now, let's find a point of intersection by setting these two equations equal to each other:

$z=x_1(x-x_1)+y_1(y-y_1)+\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{2}$ and $z=x_2(x-x_2)+y_2(y-y_2)+\frac{x_2^2+y_2^2}{2}$

$$x_1(x-x_1)+y_3(y-y_3)+\frac{x_1^2+y_3^2}{2}=x_2(x-x_2)^2+y_3(y-y_3)+\frac{x_2^2+y_3^2}{2}$$

$$x_1\cdot x-\frac{x_1^2}{2}=x_2\cdot x -\frac{x_2^2}{2}$$

$$(x_1-x_2)x=\frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$

Since the $x$ coordinate of any point of intersection must be $0$, we conclude that $x_1=-x_2$. Again, in order to avoid confusion, we create a new variable: $x_3=x_1=-x_2$.

Since these planes are perpendicular, $(x_1,y_1,1)\cdot(x_2,y_2,1)=0$. In other words, $x_3^2-y_3^2=1$

Now we can finally find the equation of the intersection line. We already know the the $x$-coordinate will be $0$, so we set $x$ equal to $0$ (we can do this to any of the two equations, the result will be the same):

$$z=-x_3^2+y_3(y-y_3)-\frac{x_3^2+y_3^2}{2}$$
$$z=y_3\cdot y - y_3^2-\frac{1}{2}$$

By rearranging the terms, we get a quadratic in $y_3$:

$$y_3^2-y\cdot y_3+z+\frac{1}{2}$$

Two find the envelope of this family of curves, all we have to do is set the discriminant to $0$:

$$y^2-4z-2=0$$

$$z=\frac{y^2-2}{4}$$

The final curve is

$$\begin{cases}z=\frac{y^2-2}{4}\\x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @VineetMangal My last answer was incorrect. This answer, however, is correct.

Comment: Thanks...but why you equate the discriminant to zero ?

Comment: @Vineet Mangal Let's say that I had a family of implicit curves $f_t(x,y)=0$. The envelope would be the set of points where $F(t,x,y)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,x,y,)=0$. In other words, the envelopes occur at double roots of $t$. So, by setting the discriminant to zero, we find the double roots. For a better explanation, look at this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)